# bucket sort on composite aggs query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have more than 100k records by zip wise i want to show them by least price order, same product with same price exists on different zip's. but i want unique providers with least price order with pagination.

for eg : Airtel, Jio, Vodafone, BSNL
i have Airtel with some offer with 100rs on all over india based on zip code (chennai, bengaluru, kolkata, mumbai.,etc..., all have same price with same offer) but i want to show least price offer of Airtel so i want only one record from all over india, like that for all networks so i used aggregation query if i have more than 1 lakh records how to show them by pagination. i used composite query but i couldnt sort outside of the composite source bucket.

my data set has

```
Airtel 100rs for bengaluru,
Airtel 100rs for Kolkata,
Airtel 100rs for Mumbai,
Airtel 120rs for bengaluru,
Airtel 120rs for chennai,

Vodafone 110rs for bengaluru,
Vodafone 100rs for Kolkata,
Vodafone 100rs for Mumbai,
Vodafone 120rs for bengaluru,
Vodafone 120rs for chennai,

Jio 110rs for bengaluru,
Jio 100rs for Kolkata,
Jio 100rs for Mumbai,
Jio 120rs for bengaluru,
Jio 120rs for chennai,
```

my desired result is

```
Airtel 100rs
Vodafone 120
BSNL 140
.....etc...
```

here is my query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "HASDATA": "Y"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "SHORTTERMPRICE": {
                    "gt": 0.0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
       "size": 5,      
        "sources": [
          {
            "product": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "STD_NAME.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "mySort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "sort_user": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "sort_user": {
          "min": {
            "field": "SHORTTERMPRICE"
          }
        },
        "top_provider_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "SHORTTERMPRICE": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```